# Memory leak while plotting with pandas and pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I an trying to create a plot for all csvs in a directory. When I run the script below, my RAM memory consumption just goes up monotonically. The code is simple albeit a bit longer:

```
import multiprocessing
import os
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

root_data_dir = '/home/user1/data/20191121'
root_img_dir = os.path.join(root_data_dir, 'figures')

if not os.path.exists(root_img_dir):
    os.mkdir(root_img_dir)

def plot_file(file):
    print("Processing {}".format(file))
    df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date', compression='xz')
    plt.plot(df)

    base_file = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
    img_file = os.path.join(root_img_dir, base_file + '.png')

    plt.title(base_file)
    plt.savefig(img_file, dpi=300)
    print("Saved {}".format(img_file))
    plt.close()

multiprocessing.Pool(16).map(plot_file, sorted(glob(os.path.join(root_data_dir, '*.csv.xz'))))
```

Comment: try adding import gc then gc.collect()

Comment: @lssilva OK this did it

Comment: prob the DF was staying around and your system was not in need of free memory to reclaim it. Aggressive garbage collection may have negative impact on the performance. So I would let it decide on its own when to collect the memory though

Comment: @lssilva I tried adding `del df` after `plt.close()` but didn't work. The system has 32GB of RAM and I ended up consuming all of it within a short period of time after which the machine became unresponsive (I am running a recent version of linux for reference)

Comment: Do you have the issue if you do it sequentially instead of with 16 threads?

Comment: @lssilva It's slower :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code

```
import gc
```

..
..
then inside plot_file gc.collect()

```
def plot_file(file):
    print("Processing {}".format(file))
    df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date', compression='xz')
    plt.plot(df)

    base_file = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
    img_file = os.path.join(root_img_dir, base_file + '.png')

    plt.title(base_file)
    plt.savefig(img_file, dpi=300)
    print("Saved {}".format(img_file))
    plt.close()
    gc.collect()
```